# Splitting Linked Lists Python

Tags: python, linked-list

I recently started learning data structures and I want to know what is going on with the last 3 lines...

```
def frontBackSplit(self):
    source = self.root
    # if the length is less than 2, handle it separately
    if source is None or source.next is None:
        return source, None

    slow, fast = source, source.next

    # advance `fast` two nodes, and advance `slow` one node
    while fast:

        fast = fast.next
        if fast:
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next

    # `slow` is before the midpoint of the list, so split it in two
    # at that point.
    ret = source, slow.next
    slow.next = None
    return ret
```

I understand that this slow/fast strategy is to find the midpoint, but then when:

```
ret = source, slow.next
slow.next = None
return ret
```

I don't understand how this allows the linked lists to be splitted. can anyone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, what is the purpose of the `.next` attribute? What does it mean if this value is `None`? If the value was not `None` before, and now is `None`, what has changed? What can you say about the node that `.next` *used to* refer to? Do you see how this represents splitting the list? Therefore, do you see how `slow.next` accomplishes this? Now, think carefully about what `ret` will be equal to. Do you see why it is important to compute `ret` *before` changing the value of `slow.next`?

Comment: In general, the best person to ask about someone else's code is *the author*. If you are learning fundamentals, this means re-reading/watching whatever textbook, webpage, video tutorial etc. you got the code from; if it's online, you might also ask in the corresponding comment section.

Comment: To clarify the other answer, you need to make a copy of slow.next before setting it to None. In this case, the copy is done when creating the pair `ret = source, slow.next` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the start of the function, `source` is set to the head node, `self.root`:

```
source
/---\    /---\    /---\    /---\    /---\    /---\
|   | -> |   | -> |   | -> |   | -> |   | -> |   |
\---/    \---/    \---/    \---/    \---/    \---/
```

The iteration moves the pointers `fast` and `slow` down the list.  By the time `fast` has fallen off the end of the list, `slow` is at the midpoint.  `source` is still where it was.

```
source            slow
/---\    /---\    /---\    /---\    /---\    /---\
|   | -> |   | -> |   | -> |   | -> |   | -> |   |
\---/    \---/    \---/    \---/    \---/    \---/
```

Now we do:

```
ret = source, slow.next
```

Note that `source` still points to the head of the list, but we don't use it after this point so it's irrelevant; let's just focus on `ret` and `slow`:

```
ret[0]            slow     ret[1]
/---\    /---\    /---\    /---\    /---\    /---\
|   | -> |   | -> |   | -> |   | -> |   | -> |   |
\---/    \---/    \---/    \---/    \---/    \---/
```

Note that `ret[0]` and `ret[1]` are at the head nodes of the two half-lists we want to return, but the two are still part of a single list.  To actually split the list, we need to sever the connection between `slow` and `ret[1]`, which is the `slow.next` pointer:

```
slow.next = None
```

gives us:

```
ret[0]                     ret[1]
/---\    /---\    /---\    /---\    /---\    /---\
|   | -> |   | -> |   |    |   | -> |   | -> |   |
\---/    \---/    \---/    \---/    \---/    \---/
```

and now we have two lists, which we return as `ret`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
ret = source, slow.next
```

That creates a tuple with two items: the start of the current list, and the start of the second list.  Then you do:

```
slow.next = None
```

Which breaks the chain by making `slow` the end of the first list.  So, when you return `ret`, you are returning the start of the first list (which now ends at `slow`), and the start of the second list (which starts at the node after `slow`).

Say we had

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
```

Where `source` is the 1, and `slow` is the 3.  When we do the first statement, `ret` will point to (`1`, `4`).  Then we break the list for 3, and we are left with

```
(  1 -> 2 -> 3   ,   4 -> 5 )
```